# Python: Opening a jpg file based on user input

Tags: image, python-3.8

Hi from a newbie to Python3,

I want to select and display a jpg file after users have input their forename (x), middleinitial (y) and lastname (z). Based on x, y and z I need to open that jpg file.

Example: Inputs:   `John (x), H (y), Hancock (z)`

Looking for file John H Hancock.jgp

in folder: C:/Users/xxxxx/Pictures/

My script:

```
import PIL.Image as Image

x = input('Please enter your first name: ')
y = input('followed by your middle initial: ')
z = input('followed by your last name: ')
print('Thank you', x, y, z)

img = Image.open("'C:/Users/rober/Pictures/'x' + 'y' + 'z''.jpg")
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "'C:/Users/rober/Pictures/ + 'x' + 'y' + 'z''.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image.open("C:/Users/rober/Pictures/" + x + y + z + ".jpg")
```

that should work :)

Comment: Hi Okon, script is running but image is not displaying. It prints the name successfully but won't open file RobertWDavis.jpg even when my inputs are Robert(x) W(y) Davis(z)

Comment: @Robert50 Does your filename have spaces in it?

Comment: No, the file I'm trying to display is RobertWDavis.jpg

Comment: @Robert50 are you sure the full path is right? have you tried putting the image on the same folder as your code and use the relative path(../RobertWDavis.jpg)?

Comment: @Robert50 How do you know it doesn't open? Are you still getting the same error as before? Your code as it is doesn't do anything with `img`.